# How to output ColdFusion Maximum number of cached queries via CFM

Tags: caching, coldfusion

Our ColdFusion hosting provider does not provide CF Admin access but want to know the value Maximum number of cached queries so to determine if caching is an option.  Is there a way to dump this via a .cfm?

Comment: Can't you just ask them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jake's answer-by-comment is the best.

Ring them up and ask them.

If you need to find this out on a regular basis (although why would one expect the value to change?) then consider horsing around with code.  But failing that, don't over complicate things.  Just ask them.

Comment: Was looking for a reusable technical solution but one phone call and I had my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could check the [ServiceFactory component](http://www.aaronwest.net/blog/index.cfm/2007/3/10/Retrieving-ColdFusion-Server-Info-Using-the-ServiceFactory-and-Server-Scope) but it [may be disabled](http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2007/8/28/Avoid-those-hidden-features) or it may require to provide username/password to get to the setting you need.

You can access it:

```
<cfset variables.factory = CreateObject("java", "coldfusion.server.ServiceFactory")>
<cfdump var="#variables.factory#">
```

Comment: Does not show the Maximum number of cached queries unfortunately.